# How do I specify two locations for Twig templates?

Tags: php, html, templates, twig

I've structured my website with a separate directory for each component (i.e. page).

```
/var/www/components/component_1/
/var/www/components/component_2/
/var/www/components/component_3/
```

Within each directory, I have a controller, a model, and a Twig template.  A typical template which might be located at `/var/www/components/component_2/templates/myTemp.html` looks like the following:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

bla bla bla
```

I have several base templates.  Unlike the child templates, I wish these to be located in `/var/www/templates/`

How do I specify two locations when extending Twig templates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just take a look at Twig Loader Filesystem http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html#twig-loader-filesystem

So can do something like:

```
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(array('/var/www/components/component_1/templates', '/var/www/templates'));
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);

echo $twig->render('Hello {{ name }}!', array('name' => 'Fabien'));
```